# Replace specific words in sentence by different names in python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace specific words in  sentences to different names each word will have a new name. for example:

```
my_words = {[ 'a','b'],['c','d','e','f'], ['l','m','n']}
my_sentences = {' w0 w1 a w2 w3 b w4' , ' w0 w1 w2 c w3 d w4 e f' , 'w0 w1 w2 l m w3 w4 n w5']
```

I want to replace `(a,'first_word')` and to replace `(b ,' second_word')` in the first sentence. Also, I want to replace `(c,'first_word')` and `(d, 'second_word')` and the remaining words in the list (e,f) will be replace to `'other_word'` in the second sentence.
 I wrote a code which replace all specific words to `'first_word'`. see the code below :

```
def replace_all(sentences=[], words = []):
     text = []
     A_regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, words)))
     for t in sentences:
         t = A_regex.sub("first_word", t)
         text.append(t)
    return text
```

I tried  another code:

```
for t in sentences:
    for w in words:
        for j in range (len(w)):
           t = t.replace(w[j][0],'FIRST_word')
           t = t.replace(w[j][1],'SECOND_word')
           if j == -1:
               break
           else:
              t = t.replace(w[j][2:-1],'OTHER_words')
     break
```

but it does not work,

thanks for help or any hints.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: the output must be like this: [' w0 w1 first_word w2 w3 second_word w4' , ' w0 w1 w2 first_word w3 second_word w4 other_word  other_word' , 'w0 w1 w2 first_word second_word w3 w4 other_word w5']

Comment: what if there are duplicates? like `w0 a a w1`, will it be `w0 first_word first_word w1`?

Comment: if there is a duplicate just it will be replaced  the first word and the second will be ignored

Comment: @S.M and if your first item was `['b', 'a']` would the first corresponding element be `w0 w1 second_word w2 w3 first_word w4` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements , no

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach, you can fix it as the following:

```
# You need to add spaces before and after each letter to avoid replacing letters in words.
my_words = [[' a ', ' b '], [' c ', ' d ', ' e ', ' f '], [' l ', ' m ', ' n ']]
my_sentences = ['w0 w1 a w2 w3 b w4', ' w0 w1 w2 c w3 d w4 e f', 'w0 w1 w2 l m w3 w4 n w5']
for i, c in enumerate(my_words):
    for j, word in enumerate(c):
        if j == 0:
            my_sentences[i] = my_sentences[i].replace(word, ' first_word ')
        elif j == 1:
            my_sentences[i] = my_sentences[i].replace(word, ' second_word ')
        else:
            my_sentences[i] = my_sentences[i].replace(word, ' other_word ')
print my_sentences
```

Output:

```
['w0 w1 first_word w2 w3 second_word w4', ' w0 w1 w2 first_word w3 second_word w4 other_word f', 'w0 w1 w2 first_word second_word w3 w4 other_word w5']
```

However, I highly advise you to use a `dictionary` instead for more efficiency.